# Not able to boot in raspberry pi only a red led is on

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

I am trying to run latest AndroidThings developer preview 0.5.1 on a Rasperry Pi Module but the module is not booting up at all.

In MAC, I am using SDCard formater for formatting and unarchiver for extracting .img file out of downloaded zip file from the console.

After transferring the .img file to SD card, If I try to mount the sdcard back in the system again, I get `If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option` as error and mount fails.

It's a 16GB class 10 SD card and the same card works fine If I install NOOBS lite.

Couple of months back, I had installed the older version of Androidthings  (before the console) successfully.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue noted above was because of the wrong drive number used in the dd command.
I was using Mac, where the sd card reader was mounted to /dev/disk3s1 and I was using dd command as follows.

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=iot_rpi3.img of=/dev/rdisk3s1 conv=sync
```

instead of just

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=iot_rpi3.img of=/dev/rdisk3 conv=sync
```